# How to show all the products on search result page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, catalogsearch

I'm getting strange results from the search engine. For instance on **"sk4072"** if you search **"4072"** nothing comes up.

[image]

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check or adjust the search settings as per your need.

Few suggestions:-

1. To have your product on the search results page, its Visibility setting must be `Catalog, Search`
2. Adjust the `Marketing > Search Terms.`
3. Enable Search `Suggestions to Yes`
4. Make sure products are added to the current store and website.
5. Mostly I add all the products to root category as well

For more info [Mysql Search settings](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/search-mysql.html)

[`Weighted Search`](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/search-weighted.html):- Weight to give them a higher value in search results.Means you can give priority of one attribute to other `Search Weight to a number from 1 to 10`

> Magento 2.x doesn't have `%like%` keyword of search.

Comment: My all Enable Search Suggestions to Yes  and my catalog search setting https://prnt.sc/qucphd

Comment: what is `sk4072` ? Is it SKU of any product.

Comment: Yes sk4072 Is it SKU

Comment: What's your Magento 2 version ?

Comment: search term result -> https://prnt.sc/quctv3

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.0

Comment: This magento ver -> this working -> https://prnt.sc/qucvrh

Comment: check this product configuration and match it with `sk4072`